# How To Read pdf attachement from email in python

Tags: python-3.x, email, pdf, imap

I am trying to Extract a Pdf atttachment from my email and trying to print it but it gives me really bad outputs.Is there any way i can extract only the text and numbers from it? 
Heres my code

```
import imaplib
import email
import os
import io

svdir = 'P:\\'

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com',993)
mail.login("example@gmail.com", "examplepassword")
mail.select("Inbox")

typ, msgs = mail.search(None, '(SUBJECT "samplepdf")')
msgs = msgs[0].split()
print(msgs)

for emailid in msgs:
    resp, data = mail.fetch(emailid, "(RFC822)")

email_body = data[0][1]
m = email.message_from_bytes(email_body)

if m.get_content_maintype() != 'multipart':
    continue

for part in m.walk():
    if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
        continue
    if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
        continue

    filename = part.get_filename()
    fg=part.get_payload(decode=True)
    print(fg)
```

Im Sorry i cant post the output here because its like really long and i cant even copy it because it makes my PC lag.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't have any built in packages to read PDF files. You'll need to use a PDF parsing library, for example https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/.

Hope this helps.